# Google AuthToken Validity for C2DM Services

Tags: android, push, android-c2dm, auth-token

I am Developing a web server which sends push messages automatically to my android application whenever I add new data on web server. But, for sending the push message through C2DM server we need to get a google Authentication Token(AuthToken). My doubt is that whether the token can be saved and used for later times also, or we should every time get a fresh AuthToken...!!!

Someone please help me regarding this..!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Google did not state how long the Authentication Token will be valid. But when sending out a push notification to the C2DM server, the response may include a Update-Client-Auth, where also a new AuthToken is included.

So basically you can store the AuthToken and reuse it, just make sure that you handle the response, and of course, if you receive a 401 Code as response, you have to manually request a new Auth Token.

See also:

[C2DM Sending Messages](http://goobr.blogspot.com/2010/11/c2dm-sending-messages.html)

[Google C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#push)